# Where to get more fuel?

Tags: ios, out-there

Googling shows that you can get fuel at gas giant planets. In my 5 attempts at the game I've seen none of such planets. An alternative way, google suggests, is stars, but then you need some kind of "ultraprobe" or what not, which is not available at the start.

What am I missing? Mining never yielded any fuel for me, and each of the 5 games I tried ended when I run out of fuel. But I can't figure out where to get more.

Another thing is that it was mentioned somewhere that the star map is always the same. Does this mean that there is some efficient path to the goal, that goes through the maximum number of gas planets to always keep fuelled up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess we're the only two players that skipped the tutorial out there. :)

What you have to do is go to the ship screen and drag and drop H or He resources onto the Fuel (Atom icon) Maintenance field. They then get converted to fuel.

[image]